# Assign multiple functions to class in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to have one master class with the methods derived from many other functions attached to it. So say I have

```
class MasterObject {
   method1...,
   method2...,
   etc...
}
```

Using ES6, id like to import these functions to assign to the MasterClass as methods. So I have tried something like this:

```
function setUpObj (...fns) {

    class MasterObj {
         constructor (...args) {
              Object.assign(this, args)
         }
    }

    return new MasterObj(fns)
 }

 let master = setUpObj(square, add, divide)

 master.square(1,2)
```

When I do this, the methods are not actually assigned to the object (I am assuming they are assigned to the this, but not as methods). Clearly I don't understand how prototypical inheritance works, so if you can explain it in terms of ES6 classes that would really help me a lot.

Relevant: 
https://gist.github.com/allenwb/53927e46b31564168a1d
[ES6 Class Multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` accepts an object containing properties to copy over. In your case, you are passing it an array, which means you will have `square` as `master[0](1, 2)`. If you want them named, you'll need to pass them with names, e.g.

```
function setUpObj (fns) {

    class MasterObj {
         constructor (args) {
             Object.assign(this, args);
         }
    }

    return new MasterObj(fns)
}

let master = setUpObj({square, add, divide})

master.square(1, 2);
```

that said, this setup seems a little strange since you are redeclaring the class every time. Perhaps something like this would be clearer:

```
function setUpObj (fns) {
    class MasterObj {
    }

    Object.assign(MasterObj.prototype, fns);

    return MasterObj;
}

let MasterObjWithFunctions = setUpObj({square, add, divide})

let master = new MasterObjWithFunctions();

master.square(1, 2)
```

Comment: This is a much better articulated answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the one above as the answer because it was the first answer... I see what you mean about the set up in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `Object.assign` take an object, so it has an idea of what to call the functions.

You also need to directly modify the `prototype` so that the functions are bound to the `class` instead of the `this`.

```
function setUpObj (fns) {

    class MasterObj { }

    Object.assign( MasterObj.prototype, fns );

    return new MasterObj()
 }

 let master = setUpObj({ square, add, divide })

 master.square(1,2)
```