# Accessors Composition in ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, mixins, composition

Let's say I have a `Thing` class which I want to be both `Hideable` and `Openable`.

Using a similar approach to [Douglas Crockford's](https://youtu.be/PSGEjv3Tqo0?t=1398) object creation through composition, I have been able to "inherit" from multiple classes.

**This approach does not work with accessors (getter/setters).**

I need to use classes as it's a requirement. I'm also finding that I am duplicating functionality from class to class, but I don't want these to inherit from a base class.

Any ideas?

The progress I have made so far is in the below snippet:

```js
class Openable {

  constructor(isOpen = false) {
    this._isOpen = isOpen;
  }

  get isOpen() {
    return this._isOpen + ' is stupid.';
  }

  set isOpen(value) {
    this._isOpen = value;
  }

}


class Hideable {

  constructor(isHidden = false) {
    this._isHidden = isHidden;
  }

  get isHidden() {
    return this._isHidden + ' is stupid.';
  }

  set isHidden(value) {
    this._isHidden = value;
  }

}


class Thing {

  constructor(config) {
    let { isOpen, isHidden } = config;

    let openable = new Openable(isOpen);
    this.isOpen = openable.isOpen;

    let hideable = new Hideable(isHidden);
    this.isHidden = openable.isHidden;
  }

}


let thing = new Thing({
  isOpen: true,
  isHidden: false
});
```

Comment: How can a thing be both hidden and open?

Comment: It can't. Sorry, it's a quick demo

Comment: You shouldn't use classes for this. Period. If your spec doesn't allow to use mixins, throw it away. The closest thing that could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance

Comment: It's almost like classes are not fit for purpose in JS?

Comment: Well, I can't even think of an instance of the Openable *class*. What does it mean? It's just a variable and two methods: setter & getter. It doesn't mean anything without some object, which could be either open or not open. So, it is just an interface or a mixin. It's just a set of variables and methods which represent a state of an external object. For this purpose we should use mixins. In C++ you'd use multiple inheritance with *abstract* classes, or *interfaces*. So it's not just a Javascript, it's the whole object-oriented logic. :)

Comment: Personally I prefer class free OOP. Like, where functionality and behaviour are inherited. So openable is neither a mixin nor a interface. Remember that JavaScript is not C++, is not a classical OOP language and doesn't need to follow those conventions.

Comment: "mixin" and "interface" are just a buzzwords. There is nothing like this in ECMA-262. But it's a convenient way of dealing with patterns while having a conversation.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The issue is that JavaScript only allows inheriting from a single prototype chain. So unless `Openable` and `Hideable` are related (an `Openable` is a `Hideable` or vice-versa), you can't inherit from both of them. This is a large part of *why* we have mixins.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess in a way I'm trying to use mixins with classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `isOpen` and `isHidden` are *accessors*, you can't just grab a copy of them, you have to access them when you want them.

Still, you can create your *own* `isOpen`, `isHidden` which use the underlying ones:

```
let openable = new Openable(isOpen);
Object.defineProperty(this, "isOpen", {
    get: () => openable.isOpen,
    set: value => {
        openable.isOpen = value;
    }
});

let hideable = new Hideable(isHidden);
Object.defineProperty(this, "isHidden", {
    get: () => hideable.isHidden,
    set: value => {
        hideable.isHidden = value;
    }
});
```

[Live example on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Openable%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(isOpen%20%3D%20false)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isOpen%20%3D%20isOpen%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20isOpen()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._isOpen%20%2B%20'%20is%20stupid.'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20set%20isOpen(value)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isOpen%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Hideable%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(isHidden%20%3D%20false)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isHidden%20%3D%20isHidden%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20isOpen()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._isHidden%20%2B%20'%20is%20stupid.'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20set%20isOpen(value)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isHidden%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Thing%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(config)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isOpen%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isHidden%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20config%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20openable%20%3D%20new%20Openable(isOpen)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20%22isOpen%22%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20openable.isOpen%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20value%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20openable.isOpen%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hideable%20%3D%20new%20Hideable(isHidden)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20%22isHidden%22%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20hideable.isHidden%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20value%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hideable.isHidden%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20thing%20%3D%20new%20Thing(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isOpen%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20isHidden%3A%20true%0A%7D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(thing.isOpen)%3B%0Aconsole.log(thing.isHidden)%3B)

Naturally, if you do this a lot, you'd want to have a worker function to set that up rather than retyping it all the time:

```
function wrapProperty(dest, src, name) {
    Object.defineProperty(dest, name, {
        get: () => src[name],
        set: value => { src[name] = value; }
    });
}
```

*(or do it by grabbing the property descriptor and updating it)*

then:

```
wrapProperty(this, openable, "isOpen");
wrapProperty(this, hideable, "isHidden");
```

---

I'd question the requirement that you *must* use `class` for `Openable` and `Hideable`. They look much more like mixins to me.

Comment: I've heard that mixins are falling by the wayside. Also, the class requirement comes from using ESDoc, and it's far too late in the project to change.

Comment: Changing to `openable.isOpen.bind(openable)` gives me `openable.isOpen.bind is not a function`. I didn't think you could bind to a accessor.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Mixins aren't going anywhere. Re ESDoc, it can't handle something simple like mixins? JSDoc can.

Comment: ESDoc basically requires classes and there's nothing that I can see where it supports mixins. I'd have to write my own tags for that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I don't know ESDoc, but it would be *really* shocking for a JavaScript documentation generator not to handle mixins. I notice [it has `@implements`](https://esdoc.org/tags.html#-implements), which sounds related at least. May be worth a question specifically about ESDoc in hopes there's some trick. In any case, the above addresses the composition of those properties. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder you've been a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that the OP's accessor approach via "pseudo private property" notation and prototypal getters/setters for `Openable`/`Hideable` classes already is questionable, `trait`s would come closest to the also doubtable requirement of using classes as `mixin` surrogates just for the sake of meeting documentation requirements.

As long as JavaScript does not provide traits natively, one has to stick to either [more advanced `class` based mixin patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732241/mixins-for-es6-classes-transpiled-with-babel/43129978#38850907) ore one remembers [Angus Croll's *Flight Mixins*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/).

A mixin's `function` body one has to write is close enough to the `constructor` body of a `class`. Nevertheless function based mixins never will be instantiated but always have to be applied to an object/type via either `call` or `apply`.

A possible solution, featuring this kind of mixin approach, that already reliably fulfills the OP's requirements then might look like the next provided example code ...

```js
let
  Openable = (function openableMixinFactory () {
    let
      defineProperty = Object.defineProperty,
      isBoolean = (type => (typeof type == 'boolean'));

    return function openableMixinApplicator (isOpen = false) {
      let
        openableCompositeType = this,

        getIsOpen = (() => isOpen),
        setIsOpen = (value => ((isBoolean(value) && (isOpen = value)) || (void 0)));

      defineProperty(openableCompositeType, 'isOpen', {
        get: getIsOpen,
        set: setIsOpen,
        enumerable: true
      });
      return openableCompositeType;
    };
  }()),

  Hideable = (function hideableMixinFactory () {
    let
      defineProperty = Object.defineProperty,
      isBoolean = (type => (typeof type == 'boolean'));

    return function hideableMixinApplicator (isHidden = false) {
      let
        hideableCompositeType = this,

      //getIsHidden = (() => isHidden),
        getIsHidden = (() => [isHidden, 'is stupid.'].join(' ')),
        setIsHidden = (value => ((isBoolean(value) && (isHidden = value)) || (void 0)));

      defineProperty(hideableCompositeType, 'isHidden', {
        get: getIsHidden,
        set: setIsHidden,
        enumerable: true
      });
      return hideableCompositeType
    };
  }());


class Thing {
  constructor(config) {
    let
      {isOpen, isHidden} = config;

    Openable.call(this, isOpen);
    Hideable.call(this, isHidden);
  }
}


var
  thing = new Thing({ isOpen: true/*, isHidden: false*/ });

console.log('thing : ', thing);
console.log('thing.isOpen : ', thing.isOpen);
console.log('thing.isHidden : ', thing.isHidden);
console.log('(thing.isOpen = "xyz") : ', (thing.isOpen = "abc"));
console.log('(thing.isHidden = "xyz") : ', (thing.isHidden = "xyz"));
console.log('thing.isOpen : ', thing.isOpen);
console.log('thing.isHidden : ', thing.isHidden);
console.log('(thing.isOpen = false) : ', (thing.isOpen = false));
console.log('(thing.isHidden = true) : ', (thing.isHidden = true));
console.log('thing.isOpen : ', thing.isOpen);
console.log('thing.isHidden : ', thing.isHidden);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Other answers of mine at SO, that provide similar solutions to related questions, featuring the same approach are ...

- [How do I organize data by common traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404165/how-do-i-organize-data-by-common-traits/43471453#43471453)
- [Composition/Inheritance/Factory - Best Pattern For This Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895466/composition-inheritance-factory-best-pattern-for-this-case/43630155#43630155)
- [Multiple inheritance using classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918874/multiple-inheritance-using-classes/43748183#43748183)
- [Class inheritance between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658437/class-inheritance-between-projects/43945623#43945623)