# How do I organize data by common traits?

Tags: javascript, oop, types, traits, composition

I'm having trouble cataloging data in a way that allows me to reference data by its common descriptors or traits.  I'm well aware of inheritance, traits (the programming concept), and interfaces, but none of those seems to be the right answer to my problem.

I'm writing a program in JavaScript that has potentially many different items or objects.  Let's say I have a datatype of `WoodenShortSword` and I want to express that it has the traits of being `Flammable` and `Weapon` and `OneHanded`.  Then, I want to define a function that takes as an argument only objects that are both `OneHanded` and `Weapon`.  Or, perhaps, only objects that are `Flammable` and `Wearable`, or `Flammable` and *not* a `Weapon`.

How can I do this?

So far, I've looked at inheritance in JavaScript and TypeScript, which would technically work, but would require a bunch of intermediate classes since multiple inheritance isn't allowed.  Like `FlammableWeapon` or `OneHandedWeapon`.  That's cumbersome and not ideal.

I looked at TypeScript's abstract classes and interfaces, but those are more about sharing functionality, not describing things. And there's no built-in way that I could see to check if an object satisfies an interface at runtime.

I also looked at the [tcomb](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb) library.  Although a system like I'm describing is possible, it's still very cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: It sounds like you're already on the right track. JS does not have support for multiple inheritance, so you'd have to take another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript

Comment: Am I on the right track? Inheritance, traits, and interfaces are more about sharing functionality, while I'm only interested in adjectives, essentially.

Comment: You could take an approach of using [Mixins](http://justinfagnani.com/2016/01/07/enhancing-mixins-with-decorator-functions/), which are not too bad to implement with ES6 classes.

Comment: Traits much like Mixins in JavaScript are about behavior. Thus, in case the OP's question is about decomposing certain behavior (methods) that operates/acts upon shared/same data (state) into composable units of reuse (mixns/traits), it was nice, providing some example code to the audience. Otherwise @Manngo 's approach already should be considered feasible enough.

Comment: @BlueJ774 ... of course you could come up with some example code that is stripped down to the core problem you are here referring to. This will make it much easier understanding the matter/your problem and answering it in a more helpful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @Manngo 's approach is not already the solution, one might consider giving
this answer a 10 to 15 min read. It implements @Manngo 's approach but focuses
on solving common composition conflicts if it comes to creation of composite
types from stateful mixins/traits.

---

Following the OP's description of the desired traits, one easily could go for
a function based mixin/trait approach. Thus implementing fine grained composable/reusable
units that each describe a specific behavioral set that acts upon its own and
distinct (encapsulated) data.

One would implement some kind of `flammable` and `oneHanded` behavior accompanied
by e.g. a `Weapon` base class.

But composing a `WoodenShortSword` from all of the above mentioned is not as
straightforward  as one might expect at first sight. There might be methods
from `oneHanded` and `Weapon` that need to take action on each others (encapsulated)
state for e.g. updating a weapon's `isActivated` state as soon as an e.g.
`takeInLeftHand` method of `oneHanded` gets invoked, or visa verce  in case
a weapon's `deactivate` action takes place. It then was nice getting updated
the inner `isInHand` state of `oneHanded`.

A reliable approach for this is *method modification* that has to rely
on boilerplate code, unless JavaScript at one day natively implements
`Function.prototype[around|before|after|afterReturning|afterThrowing|afterFinally]`.

A longer example code as proof of concept then might look like this one ...

```js
function withFlammable() {                                // composable unit of reuse (mixin/trait/talent).
  var
    defineProperty = Object.defineProperty,

    isInFlames = false;

  defineProperty(this, 'isFlammable', {
    value:      true,
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'isInFlames', {
    get: function () {
      return isInFlames;
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'catchFire', {
    value: function catchFire () {
      return (isInFlames = true);
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'extinguish', {
    value: function extinguish () {
      return (isInFlames = false);
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
}


function withOneHanded() {                                // composable unit of reuse (mixin/trait/talent).
  var
    defineProperty = Object.defineProperty,

    isInLeftHand = false,
    isInRightHand = false;

  function isLeftHanded() {
    return (isInLeftHand && !isInRightHand);
  }
  function isRightHanded() {
    return (isInRightHand && !isInLeftHand);
  }
  function isInHand() {
    return (isInLeftHand || isInRightHand);
  }

  function putFromHand() {
    return isInHand() ? (isInLeftHand = isInRightHand = false) : (void 0);
  }

  function takeInLeftHand() {
    return !isInLeftHand ? ((isInRightHand = false) || (isInLeftHand = true)) : (void 0);
  }
  function takeInRightHand() {
    return !isInRightHand ? ((isInLeftHand = false) || (isInRightHand = true)) : (void 0);
  }
  function takeInHand() {
    return !isInHand() ? takeInRightHand() : (void 0);
  }

  function switchHand() {
    return (
         (isInLeftHand && ((isInLeftHand = false) || (isInRightHand = true)))
      || (isInRightHand && ((isInRightHand = false) || (isInLeftHand = true)))
    );
  }

  defineProperty(this, 'isOneHanded', {
    value: true,
    enumerable: true
  });

  defineProperty(this, 'isLeftHanded', {
    get: isLeftHanded,
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'isRightHanded', {
    get: isRightHanded,
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'isInHand', {
    get: isInHand,
    enumerable: true
  });

  defineProperty(this, 'putFromHand', {
    value: putFromHand,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  });

  defineProperty(this, 'takeInLeftHand', {
    value: takeInLeftHand,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'takeInRightHand', {
    value: takeInRightHand,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'takeInHand', {
    value: takeInHand,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  });

  defineProperty(this, 'switchHand', {
    value: switchHand,
    enumerable: true
  });
}


function withStateCoercion() {                            // composable unit of reuse (mixin/trait/talent).
  var
    defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;

  defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
    value: function toString () {
      return JSON.stringify(this);
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
  defineProperty(this, 'valueOf', {
    value: function valueOf () {
      return JSON.parse(this.toString());
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
}


class Weapon {                                            // base type.
  constructor() {
    var
      isActivatedState = false;

    function isActivated() {
      return isActivatedState;
    }

    function deactivate() {
      return isActivatedState ? (isActivatedState = false) : (void 0);
    }
    function activate() {
      return !isActivatedState ? (isActivatedState = true) : (void 0);
    }

    var
      defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;

    defineProperty(this, 'isActivated', {
      get: isActivated,
      enumerable: true
    });

    defineProperty(this, 'deactivate', {
      value: deactivate,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true
    });
    defineProperty(this, 'activate', {
      value: activate,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true
    });
  }
}


class WoodenShortSword extends Weapon {                   // ... the
  constructor() {                                         // inheritance
                                                          // part
    super();                                              // ...

    withOneHanded.call(this);                             // ... the
    withFlammable.call(this);                             // composition
                                                          // base
    withStateCoercion.call(this);                         // ...

    var                                                   // ... the method modification block ...
      procedWithUnmodifiedDeactivate  = this.deactivate,
      procedWithUnmodifiedActivate    = this.activate,

      procedWithUnmodifiedPutFromHand = this.putFromHand,
      procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInHand  = this.takeInHand,

      procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInLeftHand  = this.takeInLeftHand,
      procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInRightHand = this.takeInRightHand;

    this.deactivate = function deactivate () {            // "after returning" method modification.
      var
        returnValue = procedWithUnmodifiedDeactivate();

      if (returnValue === false) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedPutFromHand();
      }
      return returnValue;
    };
    this.activate = function activate () {                // "after returning" method modification.
      var
        returnValue = procedWithUnmodifiedActivate();

      if (returnValue === true) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInHand();
      }
      return returnValue;
    };

    this.putFromHand = function putFromHand () {          // "after returning" method modification.
      var
        returnValue = procedWithUnmodifiedPutFromHand();

      if (returnValue === false) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedDeactivate();
      }
      return returnValue;
    };
    this.takeInHand = function takeInHand () {            // "after returning" method modification.
      var
        returnValue = procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInHand();

      if (returnValue === true) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedActivate();
      }
      return returnValue;
    };

    this.takeInLeftHand = function takeInLeftHand () {    // "before" method modification.
      if (!this.isInHand) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedActivate();
      }
      return procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInLeftHand();
    };
    this.takeInRightHand = function takeInRightHand () {  // "before" method modification.
      if (!this.isInHand) {
          procedWithUnmodifiedActivate();
      }
      return procedWithUnmodifiedTakeInRightHand();
    };
  }
}


var
  sword = new WoodenShortSword;

console.log('sword : ', sword);
console.log('(sword + "") : ', (sword + ""));
console.log('sword.valueOf() : ', sword.valueOf());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isFlammable : ', sword.isFlammable);
console.log('sword.isInFlames : ', sword.isInFlames);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isOneHanded : ', sword.isOneHanded);
console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.deactivate : ', sword.deactivate);
console.log('sword.activate : ', sword.activate);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.deactivate() : ', sword.deactivate());
console.log('sword.activate() : ', sword.activate());
console.log('sword.activate() : ', sword.activate());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isFlammable : ', sword.isFlammable);
console.log('sword.isInFlames : ', sword.isInFlames);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isOneHanded : ', sword.isOneHanded);
console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.switchHand() : ', sword.switchHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.takeInRightHand() : ', sword.takeInRightHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.putFromHand() : ', sword.putFromHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.takeInLeftHand() : ', sword.takeInLeftHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.deactivate() : ', sword.deactivate());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.activate() : ', sword.activate());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.switchHand() : ', sword.switchHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isFlammable : ', sword.isFlammable);
console.log('sword.isInFlames : ', sword.isInFlames);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isLeftHanded : ', sword.isLeftHanded);
console.log('sword.isRightHanded : ', sword.isRightHanded);
console.log('sword.isInHand : ', sword.isInHand);
console.log('\n');
console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.catchFire() : ', sword.catchFire());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isFlammable : ', sword.isFlammable);
console.log('sword.isInFlames : ', sword.isInFlames);
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.extinguish() : ', sword.extinguish());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isFlammable : ', sword.isFlammable);
console.log('sword.isInFlames : ', sword.isInFlames);
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');


console.log('sword.putFromHand() : ', sword.putFromHand());
console.log('\n');

console.log('sword.isActivated : ', sword.isActivated);
console.log('\n');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's a really cool approach I hadn't considered.  However, what about the case where you have something that's _not_ flammable?  If you don't run the mixin (for lack of a better word) `withFlammable()` on an object and you try to do `thing.isFlammable`, you'll get `undefined`.  I feel like having to apply a hypothetical `notFlammable()` would get really cumbersome as the various properties/attributes add up.

Comment: If you have do deal with different types and you need to distinguish them, then there is no other way then kind of a "duck typing" based type detection. You have to ask what an object is capable of, before processing it accordingly. My example just shows how one could decompose behavior and state into smaller units of reuse and then dealing with conflict resolution / method modification if one assembles composite types from such building blocks, whereas it now seems you are explicitly looking for type detection. Thus, as I already did propose 5 days ago, you should consider @Mango 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are extensible, so that an expression such as `thing.Flammable=true` is valid and will work.

To test whether an object has a property, you can use `thing.hasOwnProperty('property')`. This is better than `'property` in thing` because the latter will include the prototype chain.

A function could then work as follows:

```
function doit(object) {
    if(!object.hasOwnProperty('Flammable') return;
    //  etc
}
```

This way an object can have multiple characteristics without bothering with faking multiple inheritance.