# Is it Possible to achieve Multiple Inheritence in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Suppose my class is

```
class App extends React.Component
```

But I want to extend `scriptLoader` also to this class to use `cdn.Is` there a way to extend it simultaneously with `React.Component`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Class Multiple inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: There is currently no simple way to inherit from multiple classes. You might be able to achieve what you are looking to do by using some variant of Higher Order components though, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html