# React Native: Run method between two separate class

Tags: react-native

How to run method between two separate class in React Native.

for example:

first class

```
export default class Test1 extends Component {

    testMethod(){
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and in second class

```
export default class Test2 extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        Test1.testMethod();
    }

    render() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to call Test1 class method in Test2 class?

Comment: @aravind-s yes i do

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your testMethod should be outside the class like following

```
export const testMethod = () => {
        // ...
}

export default class Test1 extends Component {

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you wanted to modify object properties of class Test1, you can pass them as parameters of testMethod() and changes will be repercuted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it...

```js
export default class CommonDataManager {

    static myInstance = null;

    _userID = "";


    /**
     * @returns {CommonDataManager}
     */
    static getInstance() {
        if (CommonDataManager.myInstance == null) {
            CommonDataManager.myInstance = new CommonDataManager();
        }

        return this.myInstance;
    }

    getUserID() {
        return this._userID;
    }

    setUserID(id) {
        this._userID = id;
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it...

```js
import CommonDataManager from './CommonDataManager';


// When storing data.
let commonData = CommonDataManager.getInstance();
commonData.setUserID("User1");


// When retrieving stored data.
let commonData = CommonDataManager.getInstance();
let userId = commonData.getUserID();
console.log(userId);
```

Hope this works out for you :)