# Typescript type intersection and constructor

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I want to make my compound type from pieces which have their constructor called. How can I do or mimic this? I can't call super() in inplementation and can't use extend since *Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.* And I don't know how to directly create an object of type person.

```js
class bar {
  j: number;
  constructor() {
    this.j = 20;
  }
}

class baz {
  i: number;
  constructor() {
    this.i = 10;
  }
}

type person = bar & baz;

class p implements person {
  i: number;
  j: number;
  constructor() {}
}

let _p = new p();
alert(_p.i) //undefined, want it to be 10
```

Answer (score 3):

If your TypeScript target language is set below es6, classes are compiled into functions. If you are comfortable with code that relies on how classes are actually implemented in the runtime environment, you can just call them directly in the constructor that implements the intersection:

```
class p implements person {
  i: number;
  j: number;
  constructor() {
    bar.call(this);
    baz.call(this);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work with real es6 classes - you can't call class constructor without `new`. You will have to implement something like mixin composition, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance) for examples.

Comment: How can I omit this bar/baz reference in p class? I want it to be composition-independent so it shouldn't know about his parts.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to declare intersection type, then have an implementation that refers to intersection type only, not to its constituents, but somehow implements everything that constituents must provide? That's not possible.