# add two objects to the prototype chain without chaining themself

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I have two unchaind Classes. Lets say `Music` and `Entertainment`. I want `Spotify` to have both of them in it's prototype chain but I don't want to link `Music` and `Entertainment` with each other. Is this possible? As I understand the prototype-chain consists of a linked list of objects. But doesn't this mean I can't include `Music` and `Entertainment` at once into `Spotify`'s prototype-chain, without linking them themselves?

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance/45332959).