# Combine two classes, a.k.a. multiple inheritance

Tags: javascript

I have gone down the "JavaScript can't do multiple inheritance, but..." rabbit-hole and this is where I have ended up. I have got some basic functionality going, but a large part of why I am using classes is to enforce some basic validation and there are some key aspects I just can't get working despite a lot of searching. I have done up some example code below – in this example I have a Car class and an Aircraft class and I want to combine the both into a FlyingCar class.

```js
class Car {

    #color

    constructor() {

        Object.defineProperty(this, "Color", {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return this.#color
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if (value && typeof value !== 'string') {
                    return console.error('Error: Color must be a string')
                }
                this.#color = value
            }
        })
    }
}

class Aircraft {

    #wingspan

    constructor() {

        Object.defineProperty(this, "Wingspan", {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return this.#wingspan
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if (value && typeof value !== 'number') {
                    return console.error('Error: Wingspan must be a number')
                }
                this.#wingspan = value
            }
        })
    }

    static fly() {
        console.log('whhhhheeeee! I am flying!')
    }
}

class FlyingCar extends Car {
    constructor() {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, Aircraft) // using Aircraft as a kind of mixin
        // Object.preventExtensions(this) // can’t do this as it prevents me from accessing Aircraft properties
    }
}

// put it all together
const flyingCar = new FlyingCar()
flyingCar.Color = 42 // returns an error as expected :-)
flyingCar.Wingspan = 'green' // should fail as wingspan is not a number. But is allowed :(
FlyingCar.fly() // doesn't work.  Seems like static properties are not carried through with Object.assign :(
flyingCar.FavoriteIceCream = 'chocolate' // should fail with object is not extensible, but is allowed :(
```

The code at the bottom shows what isn't working but to pull this out:

- I can copy *properties* across from Aircraft using `Object.assign` but I can't seem to copy across the property *definitions*
- `Object.assign` doesn't copy across static methods
- I can't close off the class using `Object.preventExtensions` as this prevents me from assigning properties belonging to the Aircraft class

I'd like to have a class-based solution, but would consider a factory (a function that returns a new FlyingCar). I haven't tried proxies as they just seem overly complex but maybe they could be useful.

I am after a JavaScript-only solution, no TypeScript.

Comment: FlyingCar does not extend - Aircraft, so it won't trigger - Aircraft.set method. This also explains with flyingCar.fly won't work either. Why is flyingCar not extensible - its not frozen or made immutable. Its an object so also - flyingCar.FavoriteIceCream will work

Comment: The line "flyingCar.fly()" can never work from my understanding. Static methods can't be called by class instances, but only by the class itself. Even if flyingCar would be an instance of Aircraft.

Comment: Why, at first place, does the OP use class syntax everywhere when the goal anyhow is a mixin based approach?

Comment: Thanks @ConradNeumann I've edited my code to say FlyingCar.fly() ... and this does work when FlyingCar extends Aircraft.  But of course FlyingCar can't inherit both Car and Aircraft (the multiple inheritance problem)

Comment: And why has a `fly` method do be static?

Comment: I guess it doesn't in this example but of course I am not trying to make a flying car :-)  In the real world I need to be able to combine classes and have static properties "inherit"

Comment: Another problem, I think, is the use of Object.assign(). I'm not 100% sure about this, but I always thought, this method only carries over properties and not methods? You could however define a property "fly" with a function definition. Besides that, I think you can only redefine your class structure, to avoid multiple inheritance.

Comment: @PeterSeliger the goal is not a "mixin based approach"  -the goal is to be able to take these two classes, and achieve the three outcomes I am after (transfer property definitions, transfer static methods and close off the class). It may be that I have reached the limits of what Javascript can do, but thought I would post here before either giving up, or continuing even deeper down this rabbit hole :-)

Comment: @ConradNeumann - `Object.assign` copies the *values* of the source's own, enumerable properties. So whether it copies methods depends on whether those methods are own properties and whether they're enumerable. Methods created via method definitions in a `class` construct are neither (they're inherited from the class prototype, and marked non-enumerable), which is probably why you're used to seeing `Object.assign` skip them. :-) But a key thing for the above is that `Object.assign` copies *values*, not definitions, just like `target.x = source.x` does. So the target property isn't an accessor.

Comment: True multiple inheritance (MI) can never be achieved with JS because with subclassing one can only extend from one class at time. There is also no way of achieving something similar to more than just one valid `super` call. Thus, every approach which claims to do MI will implement always glue-code which copies properties over. If done correctly, it even does achieve this within two steps. Copying over own properties/methods and copying over those which are referred by the prototypes. Nevertheless the prototype chain is not capable of representing a true (multiple) inheritance schema.

Comment: @kennarddh actually yes I think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879267/es6-class-multiple-inheritance does answer this.  So using this method the key lines become
`const Aircraft = (Aircraft) => class extends Aircraft { ...` and
`class FlyingCar extends Aircraft(Car) { ...`

tbh I have no idea _why_ this works, but it does work. If anyone could provide a clear explanation to what is actually going on in this solution I'd accept that as an answer. 

Or failing this I'll post the revised code and mark that as the answer

Comment: .... and just clicked the 'similar' question button which seems like its kind of a one-way trip, and has closed this thread.  Didn't realise that would happen, In any case, thanks all

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly recommend using composition, not inheritance, to create your `FlyingCar` class. JavaScript simply does not have multiple inheritance, and attempts to fake it are doomed to fail in various ways, sometimes subtle ways.

But let's first look at why your current implementation doesn't work, and what we could do to make it work following that approach.

`Object.assign` copies the *current value* of an accessor, not the accessor itself, as though you'd done `target.prop = source.prop`. You can see that here:

```js
const obj = {
    get random() {
        return Math.random();
    }
};
console.log("Using obj directly:");
console.log(obj.random); // Some random value
console.log(obj.random); // Another random value
console.log(obj.random); // Some third random value

const copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log("Using copy from Object.assign:");
console.log(copy.random); // The same
console.log(copy.random); // ...value every...
console.log(copy.random); // ...time
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

So we can't just use `Object.assign` for this.

Separately, to use `Aircraft` instance properties and fields (both `Wingspan` and `#wingspan` are instance-specific), you'll need an instance of `Aircraft` — those don't exist on the `Aircraft` constructor function or on `Aircraft.prototype`. We can solve that by having a private field on the `FlyingCar` instance. Then we can create instance properties for the `Aircraft` properties and methods and delegate to that `Aircraft` instance. Similarly, to get the `fly` static method, we can delegate `Aircraft` properties and methods to `Aircraft` from `FlyingCar`.

That could look something like this (note that `addFacades` is just a *sketch*, not an all-singing, all-dancing implementation [for instance, it doesn't try to handle inherited properties]):

```js
"use strict";

function addFacades(target, source) {
    for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source)) {
        if (
            typeof source !== "function" ||
            (name !== "prototype" && name !== "name" && name !== "length")
        ) {
            const sourceDescr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
            const targetDescr = {
                enumerable: sourceDescr.enumerable,
                get: () => {
                    return source[name];
                },
            };
            if (sourceDescr.writable || sourceDescr.set) {
                targetDescr.set = (value) => {
                    source[name] = value;
                };
            }
            Object.defineProperty(target, name, targetDescr);
        }
    }
}

class Car {
    #color;

    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "Color", {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return this.#color;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if (value && typeof value !== "string") {
                    return console.error("Error: Color must be a string");
                }
                this.#color = value;
            },
        });
    }
}

class Aircraft {
    #wingspan;

    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "Wingspan", {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return this.#wingspan;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if (value && typeof value !== "number") {
                    return console.error("Error: Wingspan must be a number");
                }
                this.#wingspan = value;
            },
        });
    }

    static fly() {
        console.log("whhhhheeeee! I am flying!");
    }
}

class FlyingCar extends Car {
    #aircraft;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#aircraft = new Aircraft();
        // Handle instance/prototype properties
        addFacades(this, this.#aircraft);
        Object.preventExtensions(this);
    }
}
// Handle statics
console.log("fly" in Aircraft);
console.log(Object.hasOwn(Aircraft, "fly"));
addFacades(FlyingCar, Aircraft);

// put it all together
const flyingCar = new FlyingCar();
flyingCar.Color = 42; // returns an error as expected
flyingCar.Wingspan = "green"; // returns an error as expected
FlyingCar.fly(); // works
flyingCar.FavoriteIceCream = "chocolate"; // fails
```

Note that in order to get an actual *error* from assigning to `flyingCar.FavoriteIceCream`, you need this code to be in strict mode. (Maybe yours is, if it's in a module. In the above, since it's not a module, I needed the directive.)

At this point, `FlyingCar` inherits from `Car` and mixes in `Aircraft`. That is, it's half inheritance and half composition. That might be reasonable if the class is "mostly" a `Car` and only partially an `Aircraft`, but it's still...assymmetrical. That lack of balance suggests it's not the best approach.

Which brings us back to: I'd use composition, not inheritance, and I'd probably lean toward doing it manually rather than using `addFacades` above. Perhaps something like this:

```js
"use strict";

class Car {
    #color; // If this should always be a string, it should have a default value

    get color() {
        return this.#color;
    }

    set color(value) {
        // I removed the `value &&` that used to be on the `if` below, because it
        // shouldn't be there. `0` is a falsy value that isn't a string (as are
        // several others -- `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, `false`, ...), you don't
        // want to assign those to your `#color` field either.
        if (typeof value !== "string") {
            // (In your real code I assume you `throw` here, but doing it this way
            // is convenient for your example so I suspect that's why you did it).
            return console.error("Error: color must be a string");
        }
        this.#color = value;
    }
}

class Aircraft {
    #wingspan; // If this should always be a number, it should have default value

    get wingspan() {
        return this.#wingspan;
    }

    set wingspan(value) {
        // As with `color`, I've removed the `value &&` part of the below. `""` is a
        // falsy value (as are several others that aren't numbers -- `undefined`,
        // `null`, `false`, ...). You don't want to assign those to `#wingspam`.
        if (value && typeof value !== "number") {
            // (In your real code I assume you `throw` here, but doing it this way
            // is convenient for your example so I suspect that's why you did it).
            return console.error("Error: wingspan must be a number");
        }
        this.#wingspan = value;
    }

    static fly() {
        console.log("whhhhheeeee! I am flying!");
    }
}

class FlyingCar {
    #car;
    #aircraft;

    constructor() {
        this.#car = new Car();
        this.#aircraft = new Aircraft();
        Object.preventExtensions(this);
    }

    get color() {
        return this.#car.color;
    }

    set color(value) {
        this.#car.color = value;
    }

    get wingspan() {
        return this.#aircraft.wingspan;
    }

    set wingspan(value) {
        this.#aircraft.wingspan = value;
    }

    static fly() {
        return Aircraft.fly();
    }
}

// put it all together
const flyingCar = new FlyingCar();
flyingCar.color = 42; // returns an error as expected
flyingCar.wingspan = "green"; // returns an error as expected
flyingCar.color = "green"; // works
flyingCar.wingspan = 42; // works
console.log(`color = ${flyingCar.color}`);
console.log(`wingspan = ${flyingCar.wingspan}`);
FlyingCar.fly(); // works
flyingCar.favoriteIceCream = "chocolate"; // fails
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(In the above, I've also used accessor definitions rather than `Object.defineProperty` to create the accessors for `#color` and `#wingspan`, and used standard JavaScript naming conventions [`color`, rather than `Color`, and the same for `wingspan`/`Wingspan`].)

But if you wanted to do it more automatically, look for the various mixin helpers that people have built, or build your own (perhaps starting from `addFacades`).

Comment: Nice example; Because the above solutions clearly demonstrates that one needs to know in detail about the class implementation(s) one wants to _"fake-inherit"_ in order to present the leanest possible and safe solution.

Comment: @kiwichris ... A generic approach which tries to take into account every aspect of classes which e.g. make use of private member syntax and getter/setter functionality might never be stable/reliable. Moreover one needs to introduces aggregation and forwarding at instance level and never could truly cover the inheritance chain for already just two involved classes. And at this point one has not even started taking conflict resolution into account.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - Well, the facade approach gives you some level of not-needing-the-details, but as you say, at some point you **are** going to run into trouble going that route (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the route of mixins, it could look like this. But the problem of using `Object.assign` is that you assign properties to the FlyingCar class outside of the class itself, which is not very OOP.

```js
let carMixin = {
  color:"red",
  drive() {
    console.log(`vroom`);
  }
};
let planeMixin = {
  wingspan:4,
  fly() {
    console.log(`flying`);
  }
};
class FlyingCar {
   constructor(){
     console.log(this.color)
     console.log(this.wingspan)
   }
}
Object.assign(FlyingCar.prototype, carMixin);
Object.assign(FlyingCar.prototype, planeMixin);
let f = new FlyingCar()
f.drive()
f.fly()
```